# How to convert array to json object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the array in the following pattern:

```
[["abc","def"],["dss","ddd"]]
```

I need to convert it into an array of json objects:

```
[{"wf":"abc","sb":"def"},{"wf":"dss","sb":"ddd"}]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tq9et7bo/15/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can it be made dynamic? I have lots of data to keep on the json format.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic what you want dynamic can you please explain?

Comment: Thank you, it is working. I need like this only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var data= [["abc","def"],["dss","ddd"]];
var json = data.map(function (value, key) {
    return {
        "wf": value[0],
        "sb": value[1]
    }
});
console.log(json);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); // need string
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ekhphtss/4/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: `Thanks so much`